# Android 2.3: Animating a View?

Tags: android, animation

How can you change the coordinates of a view while its animating?  For instance, if I'm doing a translation of a View on the screen from left to right, I want the View to push everything to the right of it as its moving?

```
public Animation expandHiddenPanel(final View v, final boolean expand) {
    panelExpanded = expand;
    v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(200, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), 
              MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    final int initialWidth = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    Log.i("test", "initialWidth = " + initialWidth);

    v.getLayoutParams().width = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            int newWidth;

            if (expand) {
                newWidth = (int)(initialWidth * interpolatedTime);
                Log.i("test", "new Width = " + newWidth);
            }
            else {
                newWidth = (int)(initialWidth * (1 - interpolatedTime));
                Log.i("test", "new Width = " + newWidth);
            }

            v.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    a.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    a.setDuration(2500);
    a.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(a);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Are you attempting a transition from one activity to the next? Can you show us some code, not really following what you are asking.

Comment: Basically what i'm trying to do is have a panel that by default is collapsed slide out (like sliding drawer) from the left side and push the contents of the adjacent view to the right.

Comment: Have you thought about using the ViewSwitcher?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think View Switcher only allows you to display one of its 2 child views at a time, not a partial view of one next to the other.  The panel is only 200dip wide.

Comment: So basically you want the current view to move to the right as the "Drawer" slides out vs. covering it?

Comment: Yep. i want the drawer to come out and move the current view to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by overlaying the main layout over my panel, placing the button in the upper left hand corner of my main layout, and changing the code i posted above to pad the left margin of my main layout to reveal the panel.

To get the sliding drawer effect, I changed the panel's visibility and applied a translate animation that ran for the same duration and used the same interpolator.